# How to create a Mongo document modelling it after two structs?

Tags: json, mongodb, go, struct, mongo-go

I made a simple api, using gingonic and a mongo database. I'm posting a simple object like this to the api to create a mongo document with the same shape. I found lots of examples using arrays but not with maps. I made this following the quickstart on [www.mongodb.com](http://www.mongodb.com).

```
{
    "email": "test@example.com",
    "profile": {
        "first_name": "Test",
        "last_name": "Example"
    }
}
```

And I have these two go structs (for user and profile)

```
type User struct {
    ID       primitive.ObjectID `json:"_id,omitempty" bson:"_id,omitempty"`
    Email    string             `json:"email" binding:"required,email" bson:"email"`
    Profile  *Profile           `json:"profile" binding:"required" bson:"profile,inline"`
}
type Profile struct {
    FirstName string `json:"first_name" binding:"required,min=3" bson:"first_name"`
    LastName  string `json:"last_name" binding:"required" bson:"last_name"`
}
```

And this is my create function:

```
func (dbc *Dbc) CreateUser(user *models.User) error {
    newUser := models.User{
        Email:    user.Email,
        Profile:  &models.Profile{
                    FirstName: user.Profile.FirstName, 
                    LastName: user.Profile.LastName},
    }
    _, err := dbc.GetUserCollection().InsertOne(dbc.ctx, newUser)
    return err
}
```

It will create a document, but like this (so without the subdocument profile):

```
{
    "email": "test@example.com",
    "first_name": "Test",
    "last_name": "Example"
}
```

Creating a new document without go structs works fine. So how do I model a json object using go structs containing subdocuments? I couldn't find much examples, not even on github. Anybody want to point me in the right direction?

```
newUser := bson.D{
    bson.E{Key: "email", Value: user.Email},
     bson.E{Key: "profile", Value: bson.D{
    bson.E{Key: "first_name", Value: user.Profile.FirstName},
    bson.E{Key: "last_name", Value: user.Profile.LastName},
     }},
}
```

Comment: @arun-sudhakaran Thanks for helping out with the formatting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You used `bson:"profile,inline"` tag, telling it to inline, that's why there is no subdocument in your DB. It does exactly what you ask it to do.

Drop the `,inline` option if you don't want to inline the profile but have a subdocument:

```
Profile *Profile `json:"profile" binding:"required" bson:"profile"`
```

Comment: Oh wow, that was it! Thank you. I was so focused on the 'problem' I forgot about the inline tag, well read completely over it...